# Enter last directory in path and tail last file in directory

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, directory, tail

I have on daily bases need to watch the logs during our testing. This is always a pain in the *** as I always have to enter the log directory, copy the name of last directory, than copy the name of last log file in directory and tail it which takes a lot of time, I was wondering if there is any combination of commands which would do this automatically so I could alias it.

So I know to select last file/directory I can use this:

```
ls | tail -1
```

And I know to watch log file updating I can use:

```
tail -f
```

But is there a combination of commands which would go like this:

1. Select last directory in logs directory
2. Select last .log file in that directory
3. "tail -f" the last file in direcotry

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Never tail/head `ls` output; instead use `find`. That you can control various other parameters to your search. About your question, can you not find the file with the most recent update and tail it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To [sort files by date reliably](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/fef5a4701fcece77895ca9ba29129ab73a8f8207/.bash_history#L1756):

```
list_date_sorted_ascending() {
    while IFS= read -r -d '' -u 9
    do
        printf '%q\0' "${REPLY#* }"
    done 9< <(find "$1" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf '%T@' -exec printf ' %s\0' {} \; | sort --general-numeric-sort --zero-terminated)
}
```

To be able to [use `head` and `tail` on NUL-separated output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75206/3645):

```
nul_terminated() {
    tr '\0\n' '\n\0' | "$@" | tr '\0\n' '\n\0'
}
```

Putting it together:

```
tail -f "$(list_date_sorted_ascending /var/log | nul_terminated tail -n 1)"
```

Comment: Brilliant. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If your current working directory contains the log folders, you could try this:

```
dir=$(ls -dt * | sed q); tail -1 $dir/$(ls -t $dir | sed q)
```

(`sed q` is the same as head -1)